# Error while implementing bundle install in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

I was just starting with a new project called a library management system. While running bundle install in `Windows XP 32 bit`.I have also installed Python 3.3 on my system. I am getting the following error.

```
    D:\Projects\Library>bundle install
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/
dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval': D:/Projects/Library/Gemfile:27: syntax error, unexp
ected tDOT2, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

My `Gemlock` file is as follows:-

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    api_taster (0.6.0)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 2.1)
      jquery-rails
      rails (>= 3.1.0)
      redcarpet
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)
    bootstrap-sass (2.2.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootswatch-rails (0.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    carrierwave (0.8.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.5.0)
    commonjs (0.2.6)
    devise (2.2.1)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.7)
    less (2.2.2)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.6)
    less-rails (2.2.6)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.2.0)
    less-rails-bootstrap (2.2.1)
      less-rails (~> 2.2.0)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.21)
    multi_json (1.6.1)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    pg (0.14.1)
    pg (0.14.1-x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-protection (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.11)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activerecord (= 3.2.11)
      activeresource (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.11)
    railties (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redcarpet (2.2.2)
    redis (3.0.2)
    redis-namespace (1.2.1)
      redis (~> 3.0.0)
    remotipart (1.0.2)
    resque (1.23.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.0)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    resque-scheduler (2.0.0)
      redis (>= 2.0.1)
      resque (>= 1.20.0)
      rufus-scheduler
    rufus-scheduler (2.0.17)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.23)
    sass (3.2.6)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sinatra (1.3.3)
      rack (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.6)
      rack-protection (~> 1.2)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thor (0.17.0)
    tilt (1.3.4)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      execjs
      railties (>= 3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  api_taster
  bootswatch-rails
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  devise
  execjs
  jquery-rails
  less-rails-bootstrap
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.11)
  resque
  resque-scheduler
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

My Gemfile:-

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 #  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'carrierwave'
                  <-----Line 27 
gem 'devise'

gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-scheduler', :require => 'resque_scheduler'

gem 'api_taster'

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'

gem 'execjs'

# gem 'therubyracer'

gem 'bootswatch-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Can You please help me.

Comment: Please post the contents of your Gemfile and not Gemfile.lock. Could you also highlight line 27 of the Gemfile

Comment: @RobinFisher I have updated the question.Can you please help me

Comment: how is this evaluated in your file: `#gem &#039;sqlite3&#039;`, and why is like that?

Comment: Can you just remove the blank line and re-run to see if the error is still thrown on the same line. `tDOT` normally indicates an erroneous fullstop but I can't see one.

Comment: @RobinFisher tried it giving the same error

Comment: @PericlesThedorou Can you give me any other solution

Comment: The only thing weird that I really see is '#gem &#039;sqlite3&#039;'. However, I added it in one of my Gemfiles and it bundled it just fine. I know the following is somewhat cumbersome, but try remember if possible the last point your bundler was working fine, and start deleting the gems from that point on until you find the issue. From the things you've posted here I cannot figure out what is causing the bundler error. But before that let me ask you. What kind version of Rails do you use?

Comment: @PericlesThedorou,I use rails version 3.2.11.

Comment: @PericlesThedorou Removed gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' and gem 'less-rails-bootstrap' and the bundler seems to be working fine,Thanks for the suggestion.Don't Know why both were throwing the error.Can you tell me if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' and gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'give error.
I was getting the error during `db:create`.

```
C:\Sites\Library>rake db:create
[WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- v8
C:/Sites/Library/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/Library/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So I removed both of them.Instead I went to 'bootstrap-sass' gem to implement bootstrap in rails and it seems to work fine for me.
Don't know if I am correct

Answer (score 1):

OK now that you've spotted the issue I would recommend to install the 'bootstrap-sass' gem that I know works 100%.

I happened to answer a similar question so here's the link:
[how to use that gem and why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222455/rails-3-2-12-with-less-and-twitter-bootstrap-v8-error/15223348#15223348)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing all this, you can just start a project again from scratch.
Please update your `gemfile` accordingly.

Comment: I will give it a try later.Thanks for the info @Pravin Varankar